# Rotations/Transformations with Complex Numbers/Eulers Formula

Tags: complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, transformation, rotations

[image: Question]

Hello,

I am not entirely sure how to do this question, as I understand a rotation in the complex plane can be described by using Euler's formula, $e^{i\theta}$. Since this is an equilateral triangle theta is $\pi/6$ but I don't know where to go from this?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You may want to translate to tau, do the math, and then translate back. The manifesto has something to say about this kind of thing: http://hexnet.org/files/documents/tau-manifesto.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

I f a vertex of the triangle is represented by the complex number $a$, the other vertex are obtained from $a$ by rotations , about the origin, of angles $2\pi/3$ and $4\pi/3$. So they are: $b=a e^{2i\pi/3}$ and $c=a e^{4i\pi/3}$.

Use this in your formula and you can verify the result.

[image]

Comment: hey thanks, I can get the result now I just don't understand why the other angles would be rotations of 2pi/3 and 4pi/3, could you please explain?

Comment: Loock at the figure that i have added.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assuming the triangle is centered at $0$, the radii from the origin to each of the corners are separated by angles $2\pi/3$. Pick one of the points to be $re^{it}$. The the other two points, in counterclockwise order, are $re^{it+2\pi i/3}$ and $re^{it+4\pi i/3}$.